# When developing an app for another person, which package name is recommended an who should upload it to the Store?

Tags: android, performance, youtube, google-play, package

I've been searching trough several sites to find a guide of packaging naming conventions and Play Store upload process for an app that is developed for a client/company, but all guides I found seem oriented to apps developed for yourself, I know that this is slightly subject to personal preferences, but I'm a little lost and need, at least, a general guide.

I am currently developing a basic app for a YouTube user, so subscribers can see tips and videos of her channel directly in the app, my questions are:

1. Is it right if I name the packages of the app "com.isaacrf.appname", or it would be a better practice to use a package name related to the YouTube username?
2. Who should upload the app to the Play Store? Should I do it myself or is better that the final owner of the app uploads it with her Google/YouTube account? Is there any difference in the ease of searching the app or the SEO?
   Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Package name convention which is generally followed is com.organizationName.appName
2. In my opinion final owner uploading the app is better as they will have better control on what goes on play store and control all the content and other things.

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean with "organizationName"? The developer's organization or the final owner of the app organization?

Thank you so much for your opinion and help.

Comment: In best practices it should be final owner organisation.

Comment: Thanks Manish, I think I'll do it that way :)